# Visual Studio 2005 C# Control not appearing in data source dialog box

Tags: c#, html, sql-server, visual-studio

I am developing a web app base on this guide: 
http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/declarative-parameters-cs

I am able to successfully display data from my database connection, no problem.

Now I am trying to implement a search box to filter results as of user's input on the web app.

However, when I tried to link the query to one of my controls, my control does not appear no matter what I try:

[image]

I have named my box ID and it still does not appear in the Parameter properties. Below is the screenshot of my code behind.

[image]

---

As of what was suggested, I have added the server runat to my control. However the control is still not shown in the drop down box list when I tried to tie my user's input perimeter to the textbox.

Comment: The control must be server side, add `runat="server"` to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run the control on the server:

```
 <input id="RPbyRoleTB" type="text" runat="server" />
```

Comment: for both text box and the button? i have added runat="server", but the control ID still does not appear in the drop down list. Help! :(

Comment: Try using a `TextBox` control.